# ¿Se puede remplasar un childFragment mediante un boton de un Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

Quiero que se remplace el childFragment al presionar el botón en el activity

Tengo un formulario en un Fragment en el cual tengo un botón que abre una actividad de cámara, al presionar el botón para tomar la foto quiero que la actividad se cierre y se remplace el childfragment en el formulario

la función que quiero llamar desde el activity es esta, se encuentra en el Fragment

```
fun setFoto(){
        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fotos, PhotoFragment()).addToBackStack("Capture").commit()
    }
```

Estoy utilizando kotlin

Comment: y cual es el problem? te esta dando algun error?

Comment: El problema es que no se como llamar la función desde el Activity

intente con este código 
`var formulario= FormularioFragment()
                            formulario.setFoto()`
pero el error dice `Fragment FormularioFragment{4d4b1b1 (6398888e-f73a-42d2-834b-84f119ede0f1)} has not been attached yet.`

por eso le puse un TAG al Frgament para identificarlo 

`var f: Fragment? = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Capture")`

pero sigo sin poder llamar a la funcion